# componentDidMount inside arrow function

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using React Native Expo Networking to fetch data from Rest API.

As per [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/network/)  **componentDidMount** working properly inside the Component Class as shown below:

```
export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
         console.log(responseJson );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (){
    }
  }
}
```

But, I'm using Arrow function syntax for Component like this:

```
const FetchExample = props => {

   return (
   )
}
export default FetchExample;
```

How to use **componentDidMount** in this case?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the component like this:

```
const FetchExample = props => {

   return (
   )
}
export default FetchExample;
```

you're declaring a [functional component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component), so you need to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

So if you're looking to get the same behavior as `componentDidMount`, you could do something like this:

```
const FetchExample = props => {

   // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:  
   useEffect(() => {
     Your code here 
   });

   return (
   )
}
export default FetchExample;
```